# Javascript in rails breaks when there is LS character

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, encoding, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having trouble with javascript. I am making an api call that returns me some data. And using jquery I am displaying the response in html. For a particular input the api returns me this value: `https://cdn.theculturetrip.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ceMichelberger-Hotel-_ ©Alexandre-Jung-Flickr-http_-www.flickr.com-650x488-650x271.jpg` and my page breaks.

Also I tried to alert the above content and could not do it.

```
alert('https://cdn.theculturetrip.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ceMichelberger-Hotel-_ ©Alexandre-Jung-Flickr-http_-www.flickr.com-650x488-650x271.jpg');
....
```

When I paste this in notepad I can see `LS` between `_ and copyright`.
what can I do?

Comment: Also I tried to alert the above content and could not do it.
alert('https://cdn.theculturetrip.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ceMichelberger-Hotel-_ ©Alexandre-Jung-Flickr-http_-www.flickr.com-650x488-650x271.jpg');

Comment: Can you post the call or does it have your key in it?

Comment: Yes it has my key.. to replicate try to copy paste the url and alert the content. It wont alert

Comment: I alerts here...

Comment: Did you copy the first url i have given in my question? And when you paste it in notepad++, does it show the LS character?

Comment: I only seen an underscore. I do not have notepad++

Comment: If you see the link there is a rectangular box like character. That is causing the issue.. do you have any idea how can i sanitize the url.. ma be in rails before i send it to js

Comment: Try yourlink.to_json and then on the client JSON.parse(stringfromruby)

Comment: did not work that way

Comment: What does that mean? It did not encode the special char?

Comment: no it didn't encode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).
It can escape special characters but not to affect the original link target.
Just transform them to `Uniform Resource Identifier`.

Comment: He does not produce the data -  you cannot encode a string that is already breaking the JS